# How far can I get with graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, advice

I am an undergraduate who had recently finished his $2$nd year. I was wondering how far can I get with Graph Theory this summer.

I am studying from Bondy & Murty's book. I already finished Chapter $1$, along with its exercises, and I am getting a hang of its basic concepts.

My background with algebra is: a lot of linear algebra, and a good grasp of basic and some advanced group theory as well as ring theory.

I am an average student (i.e., with not much extra genetic powers).

How much could I get far with graph theory in two months, if I dedicate about $2$-$3$ hours for it per day?

Thank you.

Comment: "How far" is a rather vague question.  You'll improve; you'll know more; you'll understand more concepts; you'll likely be ready for a graduate-level course in graph theory.  You'll likely not publish fundamental research in graph theory.

Comment: Elementary graph theory (per Bondy & Murty) requires very few prerequisites, just clear thinking.  You should find that you don't need any abstract algebra to follow the book, but the sophistication of having studied mathematics at that level will be of value.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: I should have made my question more clear. I am expecting an answer of the sort: you should be able/unable to understand unsolved problems and why they are so, able/unable to understand this and that level of proofs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is: *"How would anyone know it?"* - Unless there are some people on MSE that do have a very sensitive extrasensory perception and could predict what happens with you$^{[1]}$ - A better question you could make$^{[2]}$ is *"In a course of graph theory, what are the students expected to learn after $2$ months studying $2-3$ hours a day?"*

For that answer, you can take a syllabus of a course in graph theory and *divide* the contents by $3$. For example, you can take [this one](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=syllabus%20graph%20theory). I recommend you to not just read, try to watch some lectures, for example [these lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gc8emFk-2vc&list=PL612CE2AB6F38DF9A). Some more advanced proofs in graph theory demand that you see someone doing step-by-step, but that depends on the way you learn things, some people could find it easier to just read instead of watching lectures.

$[1]:$ *Their existence would invalidate part of my answer.*

$[2]:$ *Obviously, assuming we don't have users with ESP.*